# Is "It's not a second, seven seconds away" a kind of idiom in English?

Tags: idioms

Is "it's not a second, seven seconds away" a kind of idiom in English? What is its meaning?

I am trying to make sense of the chorus in ["7 seconds" by Youssou N'Dour and Neneh Cherry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txpkLAao_kE) and I just can't make it:

> Roughneck and rudeness,
>   We should be using, on the ones who practice wicked charms
>   For the sword and the stone
>   Bad to the bone
>   Battle is not over
>   Even when it's won
>   And when a child is born into this world
>   It has no concept
>   Of the tone the skin is living in
>       *It's not a second*
>       *Seven seconds away*
>       *Just as long as I stay*
>       *I'll be waiting*
>       ***It's not a second***
>       ***Seven seconds away***
>       *Just as long as I stay*
>       *I'll be waiting* (x3)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's literary analysis. Lyrics often make no sense and the only people who can answer questions about them are the authors (which means that the "Opinion-based" standard close reason is appropriate).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I wonder if you would still qualify it as "literary analysis" if I just asked whether that phrase was an idiom in English without citing the song and without quoting its lyrics.

Comment: You may find it gets closed for lack of cited research instead. Your research would be likely to show it only occurs in this song.

Comment: "**You may find it gets closed for lack of cited research instead**" - Really?! And what if said in my question something like "I've looked through all available resources and didn't find any info about this idiom"?

Comment: @brilliant in that case, you answered your own question by finding no reference to it being used other than in this song.

Comment: @MichaelRize - If not being able to find an idiom in all my available resources were equal to that idiom's not existing, I would never ask questions here about idioms.

Comment: @brilliant  if Googling a phrase will only bring up that song, you know that the phrase doesn't  exist in the popular consciousness aside from in the cited lyrics.  Thus, it cannot be a known idiom.

Comment: @MichaelRize: It could be a play on words based on an actual idiom. While I agree that if Google yields no results, it probably doesn't exist, for OP's point of view it might very well have been a case of it being a particular play on words or a vague reference to a known phrase/story. "No, this is not an idiom" would have been an appropriate answer to OP, as far as I can deduce from the way he asked his question.

Comment: (Almost) anything goes in poetry and lyrics, in order to fit meter or rhyme scheme or whatever. Also, these words are not reminiscent of any kind of idiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  It is very very unlikely to be an idiom.  Many lyrics don't make a lot of sense, since many lyrics are included for poetic license and a sense of rhythm.